# how to get pixel per inch using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to get the pixel per inch in jquery? I would like to use it for my responsive website to load different kind of page in different dimension of screen of the device sadly its to late to use bootstrap.

Comment: You don't need either... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a very basic level, you can get this with: `screen.pixelDepth`. JQuery is not needed at all for this.

```js
console.log("The viewport uses " + screen.pixelDepth + " DPI.");
```

But, instead of writing a bunch of JavaScript to make the elements responsive, we have [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)  and [Media Features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_features). This is exactly what they are for.

Comment: yeah but sadly it is too late I am new in programming and I finish my site before knowing that my site don't have bootstrap and whenever I include bootstrap the interface was been distorted

Comment: @GodwinRomero I’m not talking about Bootstrap. Media Queries are not Bootstrap.

Comment: sorry I'm not programmer professional but thanks anyway its good to have new knowledge in programming